# How do I upgrade to Verison 22.04 Jammy Jelly fish

Tags: 22.04

I need help with this. I can'e seem to understand how to upgrade to it.

Comment: Which version are you using now?

Comment: Did you read the documentation - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades    The release announcements all had links to the various documents

Comment: ps:  If you have troubles with the upgrade process; I personally see the question as worthwhile & valid for support sites such as this, but you gave no clues as to your specific problem. You've not told us if using a desktop or server (*there are minor differences*), what documentation you attempted to follow & how far you got before you had problems... ie. a specific problem for us to help with.  Your question gives no specifics.  Much documentation exists on how to do it (*with links provided on release announcements*  (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/08/12/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-released/)

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade to the next available version from your current one, either run `sudo do-release-upgrade` in a terminal or start the `software-updater` app - it will notify you if an upgrade is available.

Before upgrading you must install all pending updates.